# How to Test RTMP Streaming Load testing

Tags: testing, jmeter, video-streaming, functional-testing, rtmp

I have a task in which we have to test the Mock Interview Video, In it, the Interviewee and Interviewer are connected via Video.

So we have to test if the Video is properly recorded or not. (Video crashed or not )
When the number of users increases the load on a server will also increase, So basically it's a Load Testing,

if yes then I want to know more about them.

If not then is there anything else that you can suggest to me.

Comment: Why don't you tell us your proposed solution to this problem? You start to sketch out your thinking at the bottom of the question but you don't finish it. It often helps to talk about programming problems with other programmers so please give us more.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is going for [Flazr command-line tool](http://www.flazr.com/), it should be as simple as:

```
./client.sh -version 00000000 -load 20 -threads 15 -host 173.23.24.25 -port 80     -app live test.stream
```

Full list of command-line options:

```
flazr-0.7-RC2> ./client.sh 

usage: client [options] streamNameOrUrl [saveAs | fileToPublish]                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 -app <app>            app name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 -append               publish local file to server in 'append' mode                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 -buffer <buffer>      buffer duration (milliseconds)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 -D <property=value>   add / over-ride connection param                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 -help                 print this message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 -host <host>          host name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 -length <length>      length (milliseconds)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 -live                 publish local file to server in 'live' mode                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 -load <load>          no. of client connections (server load testing)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 -loop <loop>          for publish mode, loop count                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 -port <port>          port number                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 -record               publish local file to server in 'record' mode                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 -rtmpe                use RTMPE (encryption)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 -start <start>        start position (milliseconds)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 -swf <swf>            path to (decompressed) SWF for verification                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 -threads <threads>    for load testing (load) mode, thread pool size                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 -version <version>    client version to use in RTMP handshake (hex)
```

More information: [Testing RTMP streaming server – Stress testing using flazr](http://techonicals.com/2014/12/testing-rtmp-streaming-server-stress.html)

---

If you want to use JMeter you can go for the same [flazr library](https://github.com/mconf/flazr), but you will have to add `flazr.jar` to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) with all the dependencies ( jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.2.jar, netty-3.2.7.Final.jar, etc) and write the custom code to load test your RTMP server using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler. Check out [RTMP Performance Testing with JMeter: Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rtmp-performance-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) for more details.